# I'm trying to get Member ID, Member Name of the people that have issued the highest and the lowest no of books

Tags: oracle

The `member` table has `member_name, member_id` and the `issue` table has `member_id, issue_id, book_no` columns while running this code I'm getting error as

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

SQL> SELECT member_id AS mem_id, member_name,
MAX(COUNT(issue.member_id)), MIN(COUNT(issue.member_id))
FROM issue INNER JOIN member ON issue.member_id = member.member_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT m.member_id, m.member_name, COUNT(i.member_id) AS num_books,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(i.member_id)) rn_least,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(i.member_id) DESC) rn_greatest
    FROM member m
    LEFT JOIN issue i ON i.member_id = m.member_id
    GROUP BY m.member_id, m.member_name
)

SELECT member_id, member_name, num_books
FROM cte
WHERE rn_least = 1 OR rn_greatest = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add table prefix in the select part:

```sql
SELECT issue.member_id AS mem_id, member_name,
       MAX(COUNT(issue.member_id)), MIN(COUNT(issue.member_id))
  FROM issue
  INNER JOIN member ON issue.member_id = member.member_id;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Oracle supports nesting aggregate functions in this way.

Comment: @Christophe I tried running this code, it was generating error as `ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY` so I added group by now its showing `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function` code: `SQL> SELECT issue.member_id AS mem_id, member_name, MAX(COUNT(issue.member_id)), MIN(COUNT(issue.member_id)) FROM issue INNER JOIN member ON issue.member_id = member.member_id GROUP BY (issue.member_id);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it supports nesting, because I'm gettng results for `SQL> SELECT MAX(COUNT(issue.member_id)) AS "Max Book", MIN(COUNT(issue.member_id)) AS "Min Book" FROM issue GROUP BY book_no;`

Answer (score 0):

If there is an ambiguously defined column, you can look at qualifying the names. In this case, it is `member_id`, e.g.

```
SELECT member.member_id AS mem_id, member_name,
MAX(COUNT(issue.member_id)), MIN(COUNT(issue.member_id))
FROM issue INNER JOIN member ON issue.member_id = member.member_id;
```